# Joining Duplicate Items and Adding Quantity

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working with two bits of text contained in `<div>` tags. One contains the items, the other contains quantity. However, sometimes I have multiple items that are the same with different quantities, therefore I cannot just count the occurrences of a string (I started by using this method and discovered that it only works if quantity is 1).

This is the code I am working with:

```js
var joinArr = $('#rechighlight').html(); //get the recieved items
var qtyArr = $('#qtyArray').html(); //get the recieved qty

var createArr = joinArr.trim().split('<br>'); //split by br tag
var createArrQty = qtyArr.trim().split('<br>'); //split by br tag

var resultingArr = [createArr, createArrQty] //creates array in correct order
  .reduce((r, a) => (a.forEach((a, i) => (r[i] = r[i] || []).push(a)), r), [])
  .reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b));


var stringArr = JSON.stringify(resultingArr); //stringify results

document.getElementById("finArray").innerHTML = stringArr; //add results into new div
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Items
    </td>
    <td>
      QTY
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="orderhighlight">AAA <br> BBB<br>CCC<br></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>5<br>3<br>2<br></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Recieved Items
    </td>
    <td>
      Recieved QTY
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="rechighlight">AAA<br>BBB<br>AAA<br>CCC<br>CCC<br></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="qtyArray">3<br>3<br>2<br>1<br>1<br></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      MY OUTPUT
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="finArray"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      EXPECTED OUTPUT
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>["AAA","5","BBB","3","CCC","2","",""]</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**What I've Tried:**

I found a way to merge duplicated values on the item side by using the following code.

```
var occurrences = resultingArr.reduce(function(obj, item) {
  obj[item] = (obj[item] || 0) + 1;
  return obj;
}, {});
```

But of course, the issue there is that the quantity is seen as a string to merge.

In summary, how do I merge duplicate string in an array and their quantity (as reflected in the expected output on HTML line 52).

Comment: Are the HTML and object structures final? I'd suggest that you'd be *much* better off working with the values in a `table` with actual rows and cells instead of a single row filled with `div` and splitting by line breaks. Similarly, the result would make more sense as an array of object instead of a flat array.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have much of a choice. The data is formatted to this setup once it gets to the point where I can edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reduce function just needs to be constructed in the following way:

```
var occurrences = createArr.reduce(function(obj, item, index) {
  obj[item] = Number(obj[item] || 0) + Number(createArrQty[index]);
  return obj;
}, {});
```

reduce the first array with the keys, and sum the array with the quantities.
Although you need to remove the last item from each array since it is an empty value from your `.split` function.

Just do a pop() in both of them.
Code below.

```js
var joinArr = $('#rechighlight').html(); //get the recieved items
var qtyArr = $('#qtyArray').html(); //get the recieved qty

var createArr = joinArr.trim().split('<br>'); //split by br tag
var createArrQty = qtyArr.trim().split('<br>'); //split by br tag
createArr.pop();
createArrQty.pop();

var occurrences = createArr.reduce(function(obj, item, index) {
  obj[item] = Number(obj[item] || 0) + Number(createArrQty[index]);
  return obj;
}, {});

var stringArr = JSON.stringify(occurrences); //stringify results

document.getElementById("finArray").innerHTML = stringArr; //add results into new div
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Items
    </td>
    <td>
      QTY
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="orderhighlight">AAA <br> BBB<br>CCC<br></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>5<br>3<br>2<br></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Recieved Items
    </td>
    <td>
      Recieved QTY
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="rechighlight">AAA<br>BBB<br>AAA<br>CCC<br>CCC<br></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="qtyArray">3<br>3<br>2<br>1<br>1<br></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      MY OUTPUT
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="finArray"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      EXPECTED OUTPUT
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>["AAA","5","BBB","3","CCC","2","",""]</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I was messing around with a variation of what you did above and realized looking at yours that I made a typo (thus why mine was failing). Thanks for the addition of `.pop` as well!